# TreeView LabelEdit unavailable from aspx dotnet Framework 4.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

I am trying to edit TreeNode Text (Label) on the TreeView directly, the following Microsoft MSDN link https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.labeledit(v=vs.110).aspx recommends to use property LabelEdit. Unfortunately, with Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition, on WebForm (aspdotnet Framework 4.5), the property LabelEdit does not exist on TreeView predefined Form. Is it possible to recommend some fix? Thx.

Answer (score 0):

The treeview you mentioned is for Windows Form :)
I think you should take a look here, for the web version : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms529261(v=vs.85).aspx